# scipy.stats.norm.pdf use for calculating a p-value in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am performing a one sample hypothesis test, and I am using scipy.stats.norm.pdf() as shown below to calculate a p_value.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

x = 98.24923076
mean = 98.6
sigma = 0.064304

z = (mean - x) / sigma

p_value = stats.norm.pdf(x, mean, sigma)
```

I get that my p_value = 2.144621812e-06 and z = 5.45485879572. However, when I plug these numbers into p or z calculators online (e.g. [link](http://sampson.byu.edu/courses/z2p2z-calculator.html)), I get different values. I guess I am missing something on the stats or coding side.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to compute p-values, you need to use the cdf instead of the pdf

```
stats.norm.cdf(x, mean, sigma)
//2.4505888408075971e-08
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. This result matches the result that I get in the link above. Is the reason for using the cdf vs the pdf that the cdf is the integral of the pdf and I am looking for a probability value over a range instead of at a single point? Guess this is more of a stats question, but your insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily put it that way, but I think you're on the right track. Just note that for continuous distributions it doesn't make much sense to talk about "probability at a single point" as this will always be zero. The cdf is indeed the integral of the pdf.